# Given queue thread state in rabbitmq when no data is published to that queue

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm using spring boot application to consume the data published for a given queue in rabbitmq. sample code is as below

```
@Component
public class ABC {

@RabbitListener(queues = RabbitQueueName,containerFactory = RABBIT_LISTENER_CONTAINER_FACTORY)
    public void onMessage(String message) {
        try {
            //business logic
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //some logger
        }
    }
```

As i know each rabbitlistener is associated with one thread that thread is responsible for consumption of data published to that queue.

i'm searching to know about **thread state of a rabbitlistener queue when no data is published for that queue**. I didn't find any relevant material to know about that, information about this is really appreciable.

Comment: The RabbitMQ queue doesn't belong to Spring RabbitMQ. This is already a RabbitMQ Broker entity and of course there is not any state of that queue on the Spring application side. You concern is not clear. Please elaborate.

Comment: elaborated my concern